# Cannot reconnect with a socket after certain type of disconnect, restart works

Tags: c#, sockets, connection

I am connecting to a remote server in C# via a socket and sending data across, upon disconnect I try to re-establish the connection by creating a new socket and reinitialising it.

This works for me when I test by pulling out the ethernet cable and reconnecting it a few mins later, but occasionally (every few hours maybe) I get the one of two exceptions while connected and cannot reconnect...

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

.......

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

If I restart the application everything works fine once again, so im curious as to why creating a new socket doesnt work. Am I missing an initialisation somewhere perhaps? Any ideas? I use the same method for connection each time:

```
public static bool OpenConnection(string siteName)
{
    bool success;
    IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(serverIp), Convert.ToInt16(serverRemotePort));

    try
    {
        client = null;
        client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        Console.WriteLine("Try to connect to the server ..." + ip.Address.ToString());
        client.Connect(ip);
        Console.WriteLine("Connection established");

        //Send the nameSite first
        string nameSite = EncryptString(siteName, pwd, initVector) + "*";
        byte[] dataSite = new byte[100];
        dataSite = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(nameSite);
        client.Send(dataSite, dataSite.Length, SocketFlags.None);
        Console.WriteLine("NameSite send");
        success = true;
    }
    catch (SocketException e)
    {
        success = false;
        Console.WriteLine("Unable to connect to the server : " + e.StackTrace);
    }

    return success;
}
```

I try to reconnect as follows in the catch, count is incrementing with each iteration of a while loop.

```
if (count % 20 == 0)
{
    try
    {
        if (OpenConnection(siteName))
            connected = true;
        EventLog.WriteEntry("Connection re-established.");
    }
    catch (SocketException socketEx)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Reconnection failed. Storing data locally. \n\n " + socketEx);
        EventLog.WriteEntry("Reconnection failed. Storing data locally. \n\n " + socketEx);
    }
}
```

The constructor simply initialises the IP and Port No. Why is it that certain types of disconnect prevent me from reconnecting without a restart, any ideas?

Comment: How long do you wait between each connection attempt?

Comment: @jgauffin - It depends on the frequency of saving to a database (parameter), each iteration is about 1 second at the moment, so if I set it to try to reconnect every 20 iterations as above, then approx 20 seconds. Do I need to use the Socket.Close() method to clean up perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

Do you ever call Dispose() on client to clean it up?

Try adding the call to Dispose() before you null out the client in your OpenConnection method

```
client.Dispose();
client = null;
```

After looking at the documentation for [Socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx) on the MSDN, the [Disconnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.disconnect.aspx) method seems like it also might solve your problem. However, I'm not sure where in your code it should go since the question shows a portion of the logic.

Comment: There is no dispose() method, would close() be the equivalent? Its described as releasing all resources allocated to the instance. I have added that now, but the error is hard to reproduce so I might not know for hours :P

Comment: Are you using this Socket class? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx The documentation shows a Dispose()... so that's strange.

Comment: Yes, thats the one, and there is indeed a Dispose() method, you're right. Intellisense hid it from me however :P seems it is "inaccessable due to its protection level". This question indicated close should suffice I think... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601521/c-socket-close-should-i-still-call-dispose  ...Since I am opening a connection in a method for utilisation elsewhere, not just in a single block - I needn't use 'using' right?

Comment: Correct (for the using statement question). Did you take a look at the Disconnect link? It has some text that talks about closing sockets and making sure the data transfer ends cleanly.

Comment: I did, it is helpful alright, thanks. If my connection is interupted though, it is already disconnected, no? Is there a need to call disconnect() or shutdown()?

Comment: Good point. I think I might be over engineering things a bit as your issue seems to be with a socket that is dying prematurely. :)

Comment: @marked let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2209/discussion-between-brian-dishaw-and-marked)