# using block with Socket

Tags: c#, sockets, using

If I write

```
using (Socket s = new Socket(/*...*/))
{
    //...
}
```

Does the closing brace call

```
s.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
s.Close();
s.Dispose();
```

Or only

```
s.Dispose();
```

?

(Or something else ?)

Thank you !

Comment: You'll have a better chance of getting the answer if you provide language tag :)

Comment: I have to disagree. The using block is not redundant. What happens to the instance of Socket class when an Exception is thrown, etc.?

Comment: @Derek I forgot the Exceptions...

Comment: I can think of no drawbacks of using the **using block** (although I know some programmers who find it aesthetically unappealing), but I can think of a few when not using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The using statement will call `IDisposable.Dispose` and that is all.

The using statement is simply a compiler trick that allows you to more concisely express that you would *always* like to dispose of the given object even if the code contained by the block throws and roughly translates into the following

```
Socket s = new Socket(...)
try
{
   // Code contained by the using... block here. 
}
finally
{
   s.Dispose();
}
```

In my experience the  using statement is seldomly used in conjunction with the `Socket` class. Most typically you would only call the [`Socket.Close`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wahsac9k.aspx) which will actually call [`Socket.Dispose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.dispose.aspx) internally.

Answer (score 2):

`Close` calls `Dispose` in the `Socket` class in .NET. The **using block** just calls `Dispose`.

*But this doesn't mean that the **using block** is useless!*

In .NET, **using blocks** are essentially just syntactic sugar for a **try/finally** where `Dispose` is called on the object implementing the `IDisposable` interface in the **using statement**. There are some differences as I illustrate and explain below.

The following code:

```
using (var socket = new Socket(/*...*/))
{
    // operations
    socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    socket.Close();
}
```

Expands to the following code at compile time:

```
{
  Socket socket = new Socket(/*...*/);
  try
  {
      // operations
      socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
      socket.Close();
  }
  finally
  {
    if (socket != null)
      ((IDisposable)socket).Dispose();
  }
}
```

Not only are you getting a free null-check, but you're also creating an extra scope for your instance of `Socket` class.

Ultimately, I would recommend using the **using block** in this case since it ensures that `Dispose` is called on the instance of the `Socket` class in the case of an exception being thrown, etc.

I can think of much to gain and literally nothing to lose when using a **using block** in this case. On the other hand, I can think of much to lose when not using the **using block**.

Comment: The documentation for [`Socket.Dispose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190731.aspx) does not support this. Whilst `Socket.Close` _"Closes the Socket connection **and** releases all associated resources."_, `Socket.Dispose` _"Releases all resources used by the current instance of the Socket class."_

Comment: @ByteBlast: You link to Socket.Close. And what does it not support?

Comment: The documentation does not support that  _"`Close` and `Dispose` do the same thing in the `Socket` class"_.

Comment: Releasing a socket closes it.  However it may not be a clean shutdown, you do need to call the `Shutdown` method for that (but note that after an exception, you're probably not getting a clean shutdown anyway)

Comment: BTW the edit is wrong.  The documentation does not say that `Close` calls `Dispose`.  `Close` closes the socket and prepares the socket wrapper instance to be reused.  `Dispose` closes the socket and does not prepare for reuse.  In fact, the .NET 4.5 implementation of `Dispose` does everything `Close` is documented to do, and `Close` calls it.  But this is not guaranteed in other versions.

Comment: @BenVoigt: But what about .NET Reflector: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3601548/1608786

Comment: So as it turns out, `Close` leaves the socket in a non-reusable state, and `ObjectDisposedException` will be thrown thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code of Socket in ILSpy or Reflector.NET you will see the following code:

```
public void Close()
{
    if (Socket.s_LoggingEnabled)
    {
        Logging.Enter(Logging.Sockets, this, "Close", null);
    }
    ((IDisposable)this).Dispose();
    if (Socket.s_LoggingEnabled)
    {
        Logging.Exit(Logging.Sockets, this, "Close", null);
    } 
}
```

Essentially calling `Dispose()` is redundant. Calling `Close()` is enough.