# Unreachable IP Socket Close Time in Windows OS

Tags: c#, python, sockets, ubuntu, udp

These codes provide send data via User Datagram Protocol. There are two codes at below. When I use the first code for unreachable Ip address I got the three-second delay.

---

***Please Look New Results Title***

---

***JUST OPEN NEW C# CONSOLE APP AND PASTE THESE CODES IN IT. (FIRST CODE)***

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] data = { 1, 20, 60, 44, 244 };
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt"));
                try
                {
                    using (var client = new UdpClient())
                    {
                        // Please check IP Address, It must be unreachable...
                       // IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.141"), 55600);
                      //  client.Connect(ep);
                        client.Send(data, data.Length, "192.168.1.141" , 55600);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt"));
                    Console.WriteLine("    ");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> **Test 1(with using)**: Reachable IP
>   **Test 2(with using)**: Unreachable IP
>   **Output:**
>   ***Test1***    label1 ---> h:mm:ss         label2 ---> h:mm:ss (Same Time)
>   ***Test2***      label1 ---> h:mm:ss        label2 ---> h:mm:ss +3 second
>   **(No exception)**
>
> **WireShark Results:**
>   **Test 1(with using)** : Reachable Ip --> Data is caught, seen.
>   **Test 2(with using)** : Unreachable IP-> No data.
>
> When I use without "using" blocks, I didn't get the three-second
>   delay.

***JUST OPEN NEW C# CONSOLE APP AND PASTE THESE CODES IN IT. (SECOND CODE)***

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] data = { 1, 20, 60, 44, 244 };
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt"));
                try
                {
                    var client = new UdpClient();
                    //Please check IP address, It must be unreachable...
                   // IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.41"), 5600);
                   // client.Connect(ep);
                    client.Send(data, data.Length, "192.168.1.141", 55600);

                    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt"));
                }
                catch (Exception xe)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(xe.ToString());
                }
                Console.WriteLine("   ");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> **Test 1(without using)** : Reachable Ip
>   **Test 2(without using)** : Unreachable Ip
>
> **Output:**
>   ***Test1***     label1 ---> h:mm:ss (Same Time)      label2 ---> h:mm:ss (Same Time)
>   ***Test2***     label1 ---> h:mm:ss (Same Time)      label2 ---> h:mm:ss (Same Time)
>   **(No exception)**
>
> **WireShark Results:**
>   **Test 1(without using)** : Reachable Ip --> Data is caught, seen.
>   **Test 2(without using)** : Unreachable IP-> No data.

**What is the mean of that three-second delay?**
I am not sure but I think I have to use "using" blocks because if I didn't use the blocks memory usage will increase very high stage. 
What is the difference between both codes? Which one is more reliable? Is there any better way? I don't want the three-second delay.

**How to decrease three-second delay to zero?**

Thanks in advance...

---

***NEW RESULTS***

> I have tried socket Close/Dispose for unreachable IP with Python Programming
>   Language in Windows OS.  I got same result namely three-second delay for unreachable
>   IP. But when I try same Python code within Ubuntu 15.10, I didn't get
>   the three-second delay.

```
import socket
import datetime

IPADDR = '192.168.1.141'
PORTNUM = 5600
PACKETDATA = "f1a525da11f6".encode()

while(True):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, 0)
    s.connect((IPADDR, PORTNUM))
    s.send(PACKETDATA)
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    s.close()
```

Comment: Please format your code, indenting it appropriately. It's really hard to read code that doesn't reveal its structure.

Comment: Okey, I did that. Thx in advance... @JonSkeet

Comment: Please provide reproducable example. With example you provided I cannot reproduce that delay on dispose\close.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've updated codes. Plase, review again. Just copy codes in the new console app. Thx in advance. @Evk

Comment: Could you solve the problem? @JonSkeet

Comment: I'll have a look when I get time, but just because I advise you on how to improve the question doesn't necessarily mean I'll be able to solve it. (And rather than saying "paste that code into a new console app" it would be more helpful to include *all* the code, so we could copy/paste into a whole new file, compile and run...)

Comment: It takes some time to close because there is pending data in send buffer (I think), but I have no idea how to prevent that. For TCP socket you could have used Linger socket option to close socket immediately without waiting, but for UDP socket that seems not applicable.

Answer (score 4):

Your UdpClient is a disposable object. You should dispose it, before you reconnect.

```
            using (var client = new UdpClient()){
                //Please check IP address, It must be unreachable...
                IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.41"), 5600);
                client.Connect(ep);
                client.Send(data, data.Length);
            }
```

or move the connect outside your loop to reuse the same connection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If you look "New Results" title at above. You can see same three-second delay with Python code in Windows. The problem is related Windows Operating System. @Peter

Answer (score 2):

The actual difference is that `Dispose()` method is not called on `client` in SECOND CODE. But `Dispose()` is called in FIRST CODE with `using (var client = new UdpClient())`. The `Dispose()` method takes 3 seconds additional time when called after attempt to connect unreachable IP Addresses.

You can SECOND CODE as below to notice the delay in printing last label. The delay is caused by `Dispose`. The `client` must be declare above try block to use it in `finally` block.

```
finally
{
    if (client != null)
        ((IDisposable)client).Dispose();
}
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt"));
```

I have also noticed that delay is not caused if unreachable IP Address is out of the domain. For example if IP of my PC is `192.168.1.20` and I try to access `202.22.1.88` then delay is not seen.

Conclusion is: delay is caused by `Dispose()`. But behavior of `Dispose()` should be further investigated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And I know the reason of three-second delay. But i don't know how to cancel the three-second delay. The problem s related Windows Operating System. Bcz I faced same three-second delay with Python code. But i didn't get with Ubuntu....

Comment: `UdpClient.Dispose()` method calls `InternalShutDown()` and `Close()` of [internal socket object](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/UDPClient.cs,70336c67f1265216). For more detailed information see [Socket.Dispose() method](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs,79b7cf68c01bbf9e) that calls unmanaged functions.

Answer (score 0):

**Decrease three-second delay to zero Solution 1(Using with ThreadPool):**

---

```
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt"));
    try
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state =>
        {
            using (var client = new UdpClient())
            {                           
                client.Send(data, data.Length, "192.168.1.145", 55600);   
            }                       
        });
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt"));
        Console.WriteLine("    ");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);   // to see easily
 }
```

---

**Decrease three-second delay to zero Solution 1(client=null):**

---

```
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt"));
    try
    {                 
        var client = new UdpClient();                                                
        client.Send(data, data.Length, "192.168.1.145", 55600);
        client = null;                                            

        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt"));
        Console.WriteLine("    ");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); // to see easily
}
```